# karatedsl - get message "too many retry attempts" retry feature(version 0.9.0)

Tags: karate

I tried to use retry feature on karate 0.9.0

```
 * configure retry = {count: 2, interval: 3000}
 * retry until response.response_code == '#(RC)'
```

But I get message error in my cucumber report like this :
[image]

Any suggestions how to fix this ??

Comment: voting to close as unclear and not mcve: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -  you need to get better at asking questions. please follow the instructions here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `too many retry attempts: 2` error means it ran the method twice, and neither response satisfied your `retry until` criteria.

Check your criteria and extend the `retry` if necessary.

Comment: what do you mean about extend the `retry` ?? .-.

Comment: @YudistiraSugandi You need to check what response you're getting back and why `response.response_code == '#(RC)'` isn't true. What I meant is if you need to retry more times, or wait longer, adjust your `configure retry` line to make it so.